# WinRAR cannot find network path

Tags: networking, batch, rar, winrar

I'm trying to write a simple backup script using `rar.exe`, the command line binary shipped with WinRAR. I want to fetch an entire folder from a network location and add it to a rar-file on my desktop computer.

How do I specify a network path as input?

My script looks like this (the network computer name I'm trying to access is `Cube`:

`rar a "C:\test.rar" -mt4 -ag" yyyy-mm-dd" -m5 "\\Cube\foldername"`
I also tried with IP in the path, like this: `\\192.168.xxx.xxx\foldername`

Output tells me the path `\\Cube\foldername` can not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working with the following command:

`rar a "C:\test.rar" -mt4 -ag" yyyy-mm-dd hh_MM_ss" -m5 -r "\\Cube\foldername\*.*`

Same as above but with additions of **-r** and ***.***.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be mapping/mounting the network drive and using it as an ordinary drive.